# get SupportMapFragment in other class

Tags: android, google-maps, android-support-library, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

is it possible to get access from googlemap(SupportMapFragment) in other class?

i test several method and get follow errors:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

return:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

---

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment)  ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

return:

> android.app.Application cannot be cast to
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

note : i cant change class to extends Fragment

Comment: `other class ?`  means

Comment: @hamedata what do you mean when you say another class? Do you mean from an activity? fragment?

Comment: use  this  ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map_view)).getMap();

Comment: sorry, i mean run in class (not activity).
when i try to get "SupportMapFragment" in activity its fine. but when i try to do same in class i got above errors!

Comment: @Sree Reddy Menon with your suggest code i get "The method getActivity() is undefined for ..."

Comment: pass context to your other class with a constructor  like how we do in adapter of listview.

Comment: How are you passing your `context` ? If you calling `getApplicationContext()`, you will see this issue.. Use your calling `Activity`'s `Context` view `MyActivity.this` or `this`

Comment: for pass context to class i use : `gLocation = new GLocation(context);` in activity and in class i use `public GLocation(Context _context) {
     this.context = _context; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call it from an Activity you have to extend  the FragmentActivity from the support library. Otherwise, and if you are targeting API level 11 and above the static method getFragmentManager could do the job(Activity.getFragmentManager)

Comment: my class extend fragmentactivity (public class gLocation extends FragmentActivity)
but i cant get map with 
map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: @hamedata Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067889/google-play-service-supportmapfragment-getmap-always-returning-null