# Is there a way to get notified when the GoogleMap is ready in a MapView object in the new Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I implementing the new Google Maps Android API right now within my app, and there are a few things that I want to do when the map has loaded such as moving the map to the current location and displaying a marker there and enabling certain overlays like the satellite view.  However, I am running into NPEs when I try to access the Mapview's getMap() because the GoogleMap object isn't ready.

Is there a way to detect when a MapView's GoogleMap is ready?  I found CommonsWare's suggestion for dealing with the SupportMapFragment and detecting when getMap() will not get null, but what would the equivalent event by for a MapView?

CommonsWare's suggestion for SupportMapFragment: [How do I know the map is ready to get used when using the SupportMapFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047257/how-do-i-know-the-map-is-ready-to-get-used-when-using-the-supportmapfragment/14047363#14047363)

This seems kind of broken that there is not a way to determine when the GoogleMap object is ready so that we can do all these setup things.

Comment: See the discussion that Ryan and I had in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the MapView directly you need to make sure you forwarding the Activity lifecycle methods through to the MapView.

E.g. to set it up, you'd do this in your onCreate()

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.raw_mapview_demo);

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapView) findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is taken from Google's sample code that is included with the Play Services lib. You also need to route onDestroy(), onResume(), and onPause().

FYI you need to check for a null pointer for both the MapView and MapFragment as the user may not have Google Play Services installed. If it isn't installed the user should get a prompt to install the APK and then you can return to this Activity.

Hope that helps.

Ryan

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  That code from the sample and also the language in the documentation doesn't suggest that we are guaranteed mMap at that point.  It suggests that there might still be a possibility that GooglePlayServices is not ready with the map components.  I already do forward the lifecycle methods.  My question is: Is there a way to know when the GoogleMap object is definitely ready for a MapView?

Comment: If Google Play components are correctly installed the code above should not return null. The docs state, "You can verify that the GoogleMap is available by calling the MapFragment.getMap() or MapView.getMap() methods and checking that the returned object is not null.". But you must do this at the correct time as mentioned above, and when Google Play Components are installed. If that's the case you won't get null back.

Comment: What's considered the correct time?  After onCreate of the MapView from the parent activity?  Is there a way to measure in my MapView this if I'm subclassing MapView?

Comment: By correct time, I just mean after the view has been created and Google Play services are installed. BTW you mention you are trying to position the map, are you sure getMap() is returning null, and not some method such as CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(), that will give you an exception if called before you've laid out.

Comment: getMap() wasn't returning null.  I went and replaced all my references in my subclass to mMap to use getMap() directly and it works.  Assuming that the GoogleMap is ready at the time my MapView is constructed and setting it to mMap proved to be erroneous.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed :-) Could you accept the answer or close the question? Thanks, Ryan