# Set mapfragment paramaters in xml

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am having an issue with initialising my MapFragment in the xml file, and I don't understand why it works one way, and not another.

While developing, I first had just a MapFragment in my main activity. And this worked fine:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:cameraTargetLat="22.320542"
map:cameraTargetLng="114.185715"
map:mapType="normal"
map:cameraZoom="11"
/>
```

It opened my map, focussing on Hong Kong, at an appropriate zoom level. However now I added some more elements to my layout, ans I can't use the `map:` name space any more. It is rejected by Eclipse.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/current" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCurrent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/forecast" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textForecast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I found already ways to set the map options from code, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733299/initialize-mapfragment-programmatically-with-maps-api-v2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138534/tabsfragment-and-mapfragment) - that is not really the issue here. It's not the way I hope to solve it but it's acceptable. I'm mostly trying to understand WHY the second way doesn't work? The map name space is declared at the beginning, together with the android name space which obviously is present throughout the xml.

Comment: What specifically does "rejected by Eclipse" mean?

Comment: I try to add the map:... elements and Eclipse tells me "Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment", so my project won't build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the tools. I have filed [an issue about it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53283). You might want to star it or otherwise arrange to keep track of it to see if it truly is a bug, if it gets fixed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Eclipse - solved by Cleaning and rebuilding the project.