# map v2 is not working

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I am trying to load map. See my code below

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
        // map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map_frag)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title(
                "Marker"));
    }
```

Log error

```
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at com.chupamobile.android.nightclub.ContactUsFragment.setUpMapIfNeeded(ContactUsFragment.java:68)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at com.chupamobile.android.nightclub.ContactUsFragment.onStart(ContactUsFragment.java:59)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1502)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:957)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:823)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.startPendingDeferredFragments(FragmentManager.java:1128)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1477)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:985)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:752)
09-27 15:42:23.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15965): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 15:42:25.299: E/Google Maps Android API(15965): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
09-27 15:42:25.299: E/Google Maps Android API(15965): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.chupamobile.android.nightclub, API Key: AIzaSyCuRYM06KNkqt5rNp5XIc0a27Ns3lhsHjw, Certificate Fingerprint: 0B2737AF8A0C3550F32CCC21EA1A143210CE8770
```

Comment: what is the problem u face map not show on screen or force close ?pls specify.

Comment: No its not force to close. Map is not loading.

Comment: please verify your key generate from console and check menifest permissions also.

Comment: I am getting force to close

Comment: u must check in device only.

Comment: Check your device + check your map-key + check if you have toggled 'on' the Google Maps API v2 on https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: yes I am checking it on my device.

Comment: your map area is grey ?

Comment: can you paste your log here and your setUpMap() method?

Comment: @Aafaq yes my map area is gray.

Comment: share your log here ..

Comment: please go to my error log

Comment: here is your error, see this com.chupamobile.android.nightclub.ContactUsFragment.setUpMapIfNeeded(ContactUsFragment.java:68)

Comment: so exactly what mistake I did,..?

Answer (score 1):

Try this my friend,

- Please try with another key.
- Check whether all the permissions have given, say:

  ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

  INTERNET
- And finally, just check with the setUpMap() method also. May be it will work

Comment: yes I did....But same error.....error is coming on setUpMapIfNeeded(); that is calling in onStart()

Comment: Can u please specify the error?? Are you sure that, u removed if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            } also??

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem after I updated the SDK and Google Play Services. This answer solved the problem for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303445/1450564