# NULL Pointer using GoogleMaps API

Tags: java, android

Im trying to find my Coordinates and show it in the Map fragment with this code but my app is crashing. Im using the GoogleMap API for it  which is up to date.

```
public class gmapp extends FragmentActivity{

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    setUpIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpIfNeeded() {
    if (googleMap == null)
    {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (googleMap != null)
    {
        setUpMap();
    }

  }
}

private void setUpMap() {

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria , true);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    double longtitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude , longtitude);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude , longtitude)).title("Im here"));

}
```

}

Here's my error Message after I compile it.

```
    09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507): Process: com.max.maxo, PID: 27507
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.max.maxo/com.max.maxo.gmapp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at com.max.maxo.gmapp.setUpIfNeeded(gmapp.java:35)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at com.max.maxo.gmapp.onCreate(gmapp.java:29)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
09-12 20:10:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    ... 11 more
```

In my XML I only got the fragment map

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: `findFragmentById(R.id.map)` is probably null i.e. it can't find your fragment in your layout. Have you declared it correctly in XML?

Comment: It is , added into first post

Comment: Just to make sure that the map is ready when you access it, I'd do what's suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047257/how-do-i-know-the-map-is-ready-to-get-used-when-using-the-supportmapfragment) (set a callback for when the fragment is actually created).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it !
My problem was that I forgot to add

```
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

In my map XML File .
Hopefully this will help someone

Comment: `class` or `name` are interchangeable