# android xamarin google MapFragment.Map is null

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, mapfragment

in Xamarin android, creating MapFragment, the code shows map, but mapFragment.Map is always null and I can't set map type

code:

```
var mapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance (mapOptions);
FragmentTransaction tx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
tx.Add(Resource.Id.map_fragment_container, mapFragment);

map = mapFragment.Map;
if (map != null) {
    map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;//never comes to this line
}
tx.Commit();
```

xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason was that the map view was not created at the point of calling

```
    var mapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance (mapOptions);
```

so I used 500 milliseconds delay before accessing mapFragment.Map;

```
    handler.PostDelayed (UpdateMap, 500);


    void UpdateMap()
    {
        map = mapFragment.Map;
        if (map != null) {
            map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
            map.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate);
            return;
        }

        handler.PostDelayed(UpdateMap, 500);
    }
```

Comment: This is a **very** bad idea, don't use delays in the form of time period as it is unreliable. Check the documentation if it's an async action (which I doubt) you should wait for it to finish, otherwise you have some other issue and setting a "timeout" helped by accident.

Comment: @Alex.F Thank you for your reply, can you suggest me a better solution for my problem?

Comment: I had the same problem. I fixed by by re-calling the map creation in onResume. Sometimes the map is not null, but if you do a check in onCreate, then retry in onResume it works. Let me know if you want a code sample, but it is handled this way in the current Xamarin Droid samples

Answer (score 1):

I'd put fragment creation code in OnCreate and map setup in OnResume, something like that (excerpt from OnResume, use whatever option to find the fragment you prefer or store its instance when you create it):

```
            if (map == null)
            {
                if (mapFragment == null)
                {
                    mapFragment = ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as MapFragment;
                }


                map = mapFragment.Map;

                if (map != null)
                {
                   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `MapFragment.NewInstance (mapOptions)` in the activity's `OnCreate` then you can extend `MapFragment` and override `OnActivityCreated` where the map should be already initialized.
You should still check it for `null` as the service itself might not be available.

This issue is discussed and explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14047363/2837443).