# Google Maps Android null pointer exception

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I want to make maps in fragment and i try from tutorial in google and after that i found some error . And i try search it in stack overflow but still cannot / not found the answer so i need your help guys why this error happen i want to know it whats wrong with my code

So Here my codes :

```
package qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery.MainActivity;
import qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery.R;
import qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery.adapter.MyAdapter;
import qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery.model.RetailModel;


public class FragmentMap extends Fragment {
    private static View view;
    /**
     * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not
     * available.
     */

    private static GoogleMap mMap;
    private static Double latitude, longitude;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapfragment, container, false);
        // Passing harcoded values for latitude & longitude. Please change as per your need. This is just used to drop a Marker on the Map
        latitude = 26.78;
        longitude = 72.56;

        setUpMapIfNeeded(); // For setting up the MapFragment

        return view;
    }

    public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();


           /* mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();*/
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null)
                setUpMap();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the
     * camera.
     * <p>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap}
     * is not null.
     */
    private static void setUpMap() {
        // For showing a move to my loction button
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My Home").snippet("Home Address"));
        // For zooming automatically to the Dropped PIN Location
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
                longitude), 12.0f));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mMap != null)
            setUpMap();

        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap(); // getMap is deprecated
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null)
                setUpMap();
        }
    }

    /**** The mapfragment's id must be removed from the FragmentManager
     **** or else if the same it is passed on the next time then
     **** app will crash ****/
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (mMap != null) {
            MainActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .remove(MainActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).commit();
            mMap = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Here the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/location_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And The Error :

```
03-17 09:03:19.163 28682-28682/qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery, PID: 28682
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery.fragment.FragmentMap.setUpMapIfNeeded(FragmentMap.java:59)
                                                                                    at qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery.fragment.FragmentMap.onCreateView(FragmentMap.java:49)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you provide the link the tutorial you are following? This implementation seems outdated. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14047363/4625829) It mentions that `getMap()` is already deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
 mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
```

with this:

```
 mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
```